# excel formula to find maximum within same cell have multiple values of right most numbers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to find maximum and minimum for right most number from same cell having multiple values, below is the how data looks.
This all values are in same cell, ex: in cell "A1"
I want to extract rightmost number, like 1.00,1.5,1.5,1.0,2.00,1.50,1.0,1.00 and find max and min from it.
I am currently using Excel 2016 version.

```
BAEK1928_TXL_1.00
44444922_FLR2X-A_1.5
44447922_FL2X-B_1.5
44444922_FL2X-B_1.0
BAEK1928_TXL_2.00
44444922_FLR2X-B_1.50
44444922_FLR2X-A_1.0
44444922_FLRY-B_1.00
```

[image]

Is there any excel formula or vba code for it?

I have tried some excel formula as below but it doesn't work as required.

```
=MAX(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("_",A1,SEARCH("_",A1)+1))
```

Data samples below where the code not work:

```
KMO6722-1_THICK_0.50
MAEJ9120_GXL_0.50
BIN76822_FLRY-B_0.50
KMO6722-1_THIN_0.50
MAEJ9120_TXL_0.50
KL STLE 2987_0.5
MAEJ9120_SXL_0.50
DIN76722_FLRY-A_0.50

MAEJ9120_TXL_1.00
KMO6722-1_FLR2X-B_1.00
MAEJ9120_GXL_1.00
BIN76822_FL2X-B_1.0
MAEJ9120_GXL_0.50
MAEJ9120_GXL_0.80
BIN76822_FLR2X-A_1.0
BIN76822_FLRY-B_1.00
MAEJ9120_TXL_0.80
KMO6722-1_FLR2X-B

MIL-STD-104_PTFE_2.0
BIN76822 _THIN_1.00
BIN76822 _THIN_2.00
MIL-STD-104_PTFE_1.0
MAEJ9120_TXL_0.80
BIN76822_FLRY-B_1.50
BIN76822-1_FLR2X-B
MAEJ9120_TXL_1.00_Sn
PLAIN_EXRD_1.00
MAEJ9120_TXL_2.00_Sn
MAEJ9120_TXL_0.80_Sn
BIN76822_TXL_1.00
BIN76822_THIN_1.50
```

Below Snap-shot of error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a VBA based function. You need to insert a module in VBA and paste below code.

```
Public Function GetMinMax(strInput As String, Optional varMode)
    Dim strMode As String
    If IsMissing(varMode) Then
        strMode = "MAX"
    Else
        strMode = varMode
    End If
    Dim varInput
    varInput = Split(strInput, Chr(10))
    Dim varOut() As Double
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim varOut(UBound(varInput))
    For i = LBound(varInput) To UBound(varInput)
        varOut(i) = Split(varInput(i), "_")(2)
    Next i
    If strMode = "MAX" Then
        GetMinMax = Application.Max(varOut)
    Else
        GetMinMax = Application.Min(varOut)
    End If
End Function
```

To get MAX you can use:

`=GetMinMax(A1)` or `=GetMinMax(A1,"MAX")`

For MIN you can use:

`=GetMinMax(A1,"MIN")`

Comment: thanks shrivallabha for this code, but it is not working for above two data fomat , i have edited in scotts comment.

Comment: @Vish I have tested with your posted sample and it is providing correct answers. If it is not working for you with other data then you need to post couple of samples where it fails.

Comment: I have posted the samples and snap-shot where the code not worked

Comment: @Vish Your data is not consistent and that is leading to errors. I have uploaded file with comments to dropbox [Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2qdijf36ct3ynf/SO_59251482.xlsm?dl=0). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you shrivallabha for this, now I am clear with it.

Comment: @Vish, thanks for confirming. If you fix those then other formula solutions will work as well.

Comment: yes after fixing it, all other formula solutions are also working very well. thank you all

Answer (score 6):

You will need to split the string on the line break then find the second `_` and grab all that comes after it.

```
=MAX(--MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),""))+1))-1)*999+1,999)),"_","}}}",2))+1,999))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

For Minimum  replace the `MAX` for `MIN`

[image]

Comment: that formula is beautiful

Comment: hello scott, thanks for this formula, but it is not working for above two data format

Answer (score 2):

With Excel 2013+, you can use `FILTERXML` to split the rows within the cell into an array; and then apply one of the **usual methods** to examine the rightmost, underscore separated segment as a number:

```
=MAX(--(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),"_",REPT(" ",99)),99)))

=MIN(--(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),"_",REPT(" ",99)),99)))
```

Or, you can just create an XML with nodes/subnodes at the `LF` and `_` and use the XPATH to return the last element in each substring; then apply MAX and MIN:

```
= MAX(FILTERXML("<t><s><u>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</u><u>"),CHAR(10),"</u></s><s><u>") & "</u></s></t>","//u[last()]"))

= MIN(FILTERXML("<t><s><u>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</u><u>"),CHAR(10),"</u></s><s><u>") & "</u></s></t>","//u[last()]"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another shorter formula option using FILTERXML function, just adopt XPATH to return MAX/MIN value and need not REPT, MAX and MIN function

To get MAX value, you can use:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"_A"),"_","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[not(//b>.)>.*0]")
```

To get MIN value, you can use:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"_A"),"_","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[not(//b<.)>.*0]")
```